# Some buffers don't allow evil mode commands

Tags: buffers, evil

Switching to `*Messages*` causes evil-leader keys not to be used and `:q` tries to quit the whole emacs instance from this buffer, but not other buffers.  Also the `C-w c` (to close pane) doesn't work because it's the last buffer instance.  I end up having to kill the buffer then switch or load a blank file and switch, or use `C-x b` to switch buffers.

A few other buffers have weird behavior like that. Any ideas on how to make it more efficient so I don't have to remember which buffer/mode I'm in?

For reference my .emacs for leader:

```
(evil-mode 1)
(global-evil-leader-mode)
(evil-leader/set-key
  "n" 'neotree-toggle
  "t" 'elscreen-create
  "h" 'elscreen-previous
  "l" 'elscreen-next
  "p" 'projectile-find-file
  "b" 'switch-to-buffer
  "x" 'elscreen-kill
  "k" 'kill-buffer)
```

Comment: How exactly did you set up "leader" keys?

Comment: Posted.  I see some documentation on it now @ the evil-leader github repo.

Comment: Can you check which state you're in in such buffers?  You can do so with `M-: evil-state`.  My hunch is that it's going to tell you `emacs` and that you may need to switch the default state for buffers in that mode.